# Show uncountable set of real numbers has a point of accumulation

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

Show that every uncountable set of real numbers has a point of accumulation.

Comment: Okay. I've shown that. Oh, you wanted me to post an answer too?

Comment: You may be interested in [this](http://dantopology.wordpress.com/2010/05/29/the-lindelof-property-of-the-real-line/) web page.

Comment: Instead of just *demanding* us to show something, how about stating what your *own* efforts have been so far?

Comment: Related: [Accumulation points of uncountable sets](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/310113/accumulation-points-of-uncountable-sets)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Hint:**

If $A$ is an uncountable set of real numbers then there exists $k\in\mathbb Z$ such that $A\cap[k,k+1]$ is infinite. Use the definition of compactness, and the fact $[k,k+1]$ is a closed and bounded interval.

Comment: It seems that it is also true that if $A$ is an uncountable set of real numbers then $A\cap A'$ is nonempty. Is it true? How could I prove it?

Comment: @Asaf Karagila sir . Can you prove  how this is coming If $A$ is an uncountable set of real numbers then there exists $ k∈Z$ such that $A∩[k,k+1$] is infinite. '

Comment: If $A \cap [k,k+1]$ was finite for all $k$, then $A =\cup_{k \in \mathbb Z} A \cap [k,k+1]$ would be countable.