# $A$ is uncountable $\implies$ $A'$ is uncountable?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

For $A⊆\mathbb R$ , let $A'$ denote the set of all limit points of $A$ . If $A$ is uncountable , then does it necessarily mean that $A'$ is also uncountable ?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it does. In fact, $A\cap A'$ is necessarily uncountable; [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/310124/12042) contains a proof of that fact.