# Is a well-ordered subset of $(\mathbb{R},<)$ countable?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Suppose $X \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is well-ordered by $<$, the normal ordering on $\mathbb{R}$. Is it then countable? If so, how to prove this. I've tried to set up a bijection as follows: 
$$
\phi : \mathbb{N} \to X : n \mapsto \ <\textrm{-least element of } X \backslash \phi(\mathbb{N} \upharpoonright n)
$$
I.e, $0$ maps to the least element of $X$, 1 maps to the least element of $X \backslash \{x_1\}$, $2$ maps to the least element of $X \backslash \{x_1,x_2\}$ etc. This is injective by construction, but I'm not sure if it is surjective.

Comment: Since you don't use that $X \subset \mathbb{R}$, this can't be right (not any well-ordered set $X$ is countable).

Comment: This follows from the fact that any uncountable subset of $\mathbb{R}$ has (and contains one of) a limit point. See this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/310113/accumulation-points-of-uncountable-sets

Comment: Try to find a rational number strictly between each two elements of X. If you've ever seen the theorem that a monotonic function can have at most countably many discontinuities, the proof uses a similar idea.

Comment: As a curiosity thing, using this reasoning you can prove that in $\mathbb{R}^n$, there is at most a countable number of disjoint open balls. This is very surprising in my opinion. As a challenge, try to prove this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assume W is an uncountable, well ordered subset of R.
For each x in W, Let x' be the successor of x in the well order.
{ (x,x') : x in W } is a uncountable collection of pairwise disjoint open intervals,
That is impossible because in each of those intervals there is a different rational and there are only countablely many rationals but uncountable many intervals.