# What's wrong with the naive "take successive smallest" procedure in proving well-ordered subsets of $\mathbb R$ are countable?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, real-numbers, well-orders

For context, I have no set theory background and my understanding of sets is naive. I had a discussion with a friend that I thought for any well-ordered subset of the reals, I could simply take the least element, second least, etc. to show it is countable. It is the same procedure described in [Is a well-ordered subset of $(\mathbb{R},<)$ countable?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3434005/is-a-well-ordered-subset-of-mathbbr-countable). However he told me I had to make use of ordinals (which I don't know about) to index into the set. Is there an intuitive (or at least relatively elementary) reason why I can't count up using my naive procedure to conclude the subset is countable? The main concern I see is about if I ever "finish counting" which I don't know how to reason about and seems subtle.

Comment: The answer in the question you link to is perfectly correct. It uses the successor function, which is well-defined on any unbounded well-ordered set. (The successor of $x$ is the least upper bound of $\{y \mid y > x\}$.) I think you should show that answer to your friend and point out that it doesn't need any knowledge of the theory of ordinals. Your argument doesn't work because it makes no use of the fact that the well-ordered set is a subset of the reals and there are uncountable well-ordered sets - it may take uncountably many steps for you to "finish counting".

Comment: He gave me the standard successor and rationals are dense proof as well

Comment: How is that different from showing that every well-ordered set is countable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given any infinite well-ordered set $X$, you can define an injection $f:\mathbb{N}\to X$ by repeatedly taking the least remaining element as you describe.  To be precise, you can recursively define $f(n)$ to be the least element of $X\setminus\{f(m):m<n\}$.

However, this map may not be surjective, and so it may not show that $X$ is countable.  For a very simple example, consider $X=\{1\}\cup\{1-1/n:n\in\mathbb{Z}_+\}\subset\mathbb{R}$.  This is well-ordered with the usual ordering inherited from $\mathbb{R}$.  The least element is $1/2$, then the second least element is $2/3$, then the third least element is $3/4$, and so on.  However, repeatedly taking least elements like this does not exhaust all of $X$: the map $f:\mathbb{N}\to X$ hits each element of the form $1-1/n$ but does not hit $1$, so it fails to be surjective.

Comment: So the "take smallest" procedure is not fast enough for arbitrary sets, even countable ones like $X$?

Comment: Well, I'm not sure "fast" is the word I would use, but that's the general idea.

Comment: maybe "powerful enough". because the proof I know using successors handles all the values at once then relates them to the rationals.

Answer (score -1):

Suppose $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is well-ordered under $<$.

We must show that $S$ is countable.

Suppose on the contrary that $S$ is not countable. Consider $K = \{x \in \mathbb{R} \mid \{s \in S \mid s < x\}$ is uncountable$\}$.

Now $K$ must be non-empty. For suppose that $K$ were empty. Then note that $S = \bigcup\limits_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \{s \in S \mid s < n\}$ is the countable union of countable sets, hence countable.

So $K$ is non-empty. And consider the fact that $S$ has a least element $s_0 \in S$, since $S$ is not countable and hence nonempty. Then we see that $s_0$ is a lower bound of $K$, since if $z \leq s_0$ and $z \in K$, then we must have $\{s \in S \mid s < z\} = \emptyset$ and hence $z \notin K$.

Since $K$ is a non-empty set with a lower bound, it must have a greatest lower bound $B$. We see that $\{s \in S \mid s < B\}$ must be countable, since it can be written as $\bigcup\limits_{n \in \mathbb{N}_+} \{s \in S \mid s < B - 1/n\}$, which is the countable union of countable sets. By contrast, since $K$ is nonempty, there must be some $k \in K$, and for this $k$, we must have $\{s \in S \mid s < k\}$ is uncountable. So there must be some $s \in S$ such that $B < s$.

Then consider $\{s \in S \mid s > B\}$, a nonempty set. It has a minimal element $s_1 > B$. But in that case, we have $\{s \in S \mid s < s_1\} = \{s \in S \mid s < B\}$ is countable. And $s > B$. This leads to a contradiction.