# Let $f: [0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ be injective. Does $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} c_n\left( f(x)\right)^n=0\forall x\in [0,1] \implies c_n=0\forall n\in\mathbb{N}?$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, linear-independence

> Let $f: [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ be injective. Does $ \displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} c_n \left( f(x) \right) ^n
>  = 0\ \forall x\in [0,1] \implies c_n = 0\ \forall n\in\mathbb{N}\ ? $

Maybe something related to (i.e. a more general version of) Stone-Weierstrass could be helpful?

Comment: @AdamRubinson A mistake on my part, I assumed that $f^n$ is the $n$th iterate of $f$, but it's obviously the $n$th power of $f$.

Comment: @AdamRubinson This is not what linearly independent means.

Comment: Also consider adding some more context e.g. if you already know that this is true for some $f$ with proof that'd be great.

Comment: @Jakobian I thought it did in this context. What does linearly independence mean here then?

Comment: Is it because the sum should be from $n=0$ not $n=1$?

Comment: A set of functions $A$ is linearly independent if for any finite amount of its elements $f_1, ..., f_n\in A$ and $c_1, ..., c_n$ if $c_1f_1(x)+...+c_nf_n(x) = 0$ for all $x$ then $c_1 = ... = c_n = 0$. You're considering infinite sums, this should be a finite sum.

Comment: @Jakobian excellent point. I need to re-think how I am going to amend the question now.

Comment: Well, obviously the set must be (finitely) linearly independent, right?

Comment: If $h(z) = \sum c_n z^n$ has a positive radius of convergence, and the range of $f$ lies within this radius, then all $c_n$ must be zero: the range of $f$ is uncountable and thus has a limit point, and the holomorphic function $h$ then has an accumulation point of zeros, which implies it is the zero function. Does this seem correct to you?

Comment: It suffices to assume that $f$ takes infinitely many different values and use the Vandermonde determinant to show that $c=0$ is the only solution to any given postulated finite linear dependency.

Comment: @AdamRubinson do you assume that $f$ is continuous? Because as far as I can see only under this condition Stone-Weierstrass is related.

Comment: @freakish maybe there are variations/more general versions of of Stone-Weierstrass that do not require continuity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you suppose that the infinite sum $\sum c_n \bigl(f(x)\bigr)^n$ is well-defined for every $x \in [0,1]$, then the range of $f$ must lie within the radius of convergence of $$
h(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n z^n \text.
$$  Then, as $[0,1]$ is an uncountable set and $f$ is injective, its range is an uncountable subset of $\mathbb R$, and any such set has uncountably many accumulation points.  Supposing $h\bigl(f(x)\bigr) = 0$ for every $x \in [0,1]$ thus implies that the holomorphic function $h$ has an accumulation point of zeros *which lies strictly withing the radius of convergence* (thanks to freakish in the comments), and this forces it to be the zero function, i.e., all $c_n = 0$.

Comment: The accumulation point might be on the boundary of the radius of convergence, no? Does the conclusion still follow? I only know such result when the accumulation point lies inside the domain (radius).

Comment: Nevermind. An uncountable subset of $\mathbb{R}$ has to have infinitely many accumulation points. And since those lie in $\mathbb{R}$ then only two can be at the boundary. I'm leaving those comments if someone wonders. I think the answer is good.

Comment: @freakish I overlooked that indeed… I'm leaving this comment here if someone wonders, and to remind myself to be more careful. I think your comments are very good.

As an open question, what happens if $f$ is complex-valued?

Comment: Related: [Can a power series have an uncountable number of roots?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3957116/791850)

Comment: Asked here: [Can a nonzero complex power series have an uncountable set of complex roots?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4813540/791850)