# Uncountable subset of $\mathbb{R}$ clusters at some point of $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: general-topology, clustering

It seems very intuitive and simple, but how would I go about proving something like this? Thanks.

Comment: This is a duplicate of [Show uncountable set of real numbers has a point of accumulation](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/218949/show-uncountable-set-of-real-numbers-has-a-point-of-accumulation), which has a solution. The answers to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/310113/accumulation-points-of-uncountable-sets) show other ways to prove it, even getting it to be in the uncountable set. [This answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/412625/12042) proves that you can choose the point so that the set clusters on both sides of it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is true, and it follows from Weirstrass' Thm : every bounded , infinite subset has a limit point. And this generalizes to $\mathbb R^n$

More formally, cover $\mathbb R^n$ by balls $B(0,n) ; n=1,2,3,... $ , i.e., for all

$n $ in $\mathbb N$ Now, by a straight-forward cardinality argument (countable union of countable is countable) , there will be at least one ball $B(0, n_k)$containing infinitely-many points. Then apply Weirstrass' theorem.

Comment: In fact, an uncountable set $S$ of real numbers has a so-lled **condensation point**, meaning a point whose every neighborhood contains uncountably many elements of $S$. In fact, all but countably many of the points in $S$ are condensation points of $S$. (In the last formulation, we don't have to assume that $S$ is uncountable.)